# Multiple images at one page in FPDF

Tags: php, html, mysqli, fpdf

I'm working on an FPDF project. I've made an HTML/PHP form where you can upload multiple images... now I want them to show in my FPDF.

This is the code that I've now:

```
$pdf->AddPage();

$query1 = "SELECT filename FROM `file_upload` WHERE ncrnummer = '$ncrnummer'";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query1);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    $image = $row['filename'];
    $pdf->Image("images/".$image,11,11,90,75, "");
    $pdf->Cell(47.5, 10, "", 0, 1); 
}

$pdfdoc = $pdf->Output('', 'S');
```

At this moment it looks like the images are placed over each other...

Is there somebody that knows how to fix this (small) problem?

Comment: You are passing x and y coordinates to `Image()`. I'd guess you'd have to pass `null` there, so that the current position is used, if you want automatic distribution across the page. Or you could calculate the coordinates from the image number times the offset you want them to have.

Comment: Do you have an example of that X and Y coordinates?

Comment: Also, I'm printing like 6 images on my PDF page......is that also possible?

Comment: What do you mean? According to [the documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/image.htm), you are passing 11 for both x and y. Try using null instead.

Comment: Surely 6 images are possible, if they are smaller than 1/6th of a page